# Please explain me why I can't set this UIButton hidden

Tags: ios

Please explain me why:

```
[inboxB setHidden:YES];
NSLog(@"is hidden ? %i", [inboxB isHidden]); // gives 0
```

inboxB is an outlet. I'm inside this initializer:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
    ...
```

thanks

Comment: Have you connected the button properly? Just try to print `inboxB` in log. It would be `nil` if you haven't connected it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely inboxB is nil at the time when you set it.

Messages to nil fail silently and (almost) always return 0. So your code would look like:

```
[nil setHidden:YES]; // Does nothing
[nil isHidden]; // Returns 0 or 'NO'
```

If it's an outlet, check to make sure you've connected it to something.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem a few times with getters, I believe you need to access the property directly which calls isHidden which I believe is a private method.

Try:

```
indoxB.hidden;
```

Comment: It is still 0.  NSLog(@" inboxB.hidden %i", inboxB.hidden);